# NUnit Moq The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, nunit, iqueryable

I know this answer is around, but can't approach to solve my case. Hope anyone can help.

I have the following async method

```
public async Task<Car> GetCarAsync(int carId)
        {
            // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            return await _context
                .Cars.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.CarId == carId);
        }
```

And the following NUnit test using Moq

```
[Test]
    public async Task GetCarAsyncTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
        var cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car()
            {
                CarId = 9999,
                Text = "Car1"
            }
        };
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.Cars).Returns(cars.ToDbSet());
        var controller = new CarController(
            new CarRepository(mockContext.Object),
            new CarModelBuilder(),
            new DateTimeProvider(),
            new CarProvider(
                new CarRepository(mockContext.Object)),
            new CarCategoryRepository(mockContext.Object));

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes(config);
        controller.WithMockRequest(config);


        // Act
        var car = await controller.GetCarAsync(9999);

        // Assert

    }
```

The controller method is also an async one which only calls the above async method. The error is the following:

```
The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations
```

And happens on the first `GetCarAsync` method above

Comment: I can't see a setup for set _context.Questions, which is where you're indicating the error is occurring?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It's _context.Cars
Error happens right there on the FirstOrDefaultAsync method. It works normally when compiling the project but won't work on the NUnit test

Comment: You need to setup your db set provider to one which implements IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Does `ToDbSet` do this? Is this an imported library or an extension you've written? The solution will end up being similar to EFCore where you create your own enumerable/queryable class that allows you to set the provider. The provider would typically be a custom concrete implementation of IDbAsyncQueryProvider. See https://github.com/rowanmiller/EntityFramework.Testing/tree/master/src/EntityFramework.Testing for a starting point.

Comment: Personally I'd find a library that will set up the db set including provider for you, there has to be one for EF6 (https://github.com/scott-xu/EntityFramework.Testing potentially). I don't have any recommendation as I only work with EFCore.

Comment: @rgvlee how do you " setup your db set provider to one which implements IDbAsyncQueryProvider."